# Call additional option methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using stickjs script and can't seem to call "options" method in code. I've pasted it below.

I'm not sure if I need first initialize "options" ie. .sticky(options ({options_here, option_2});

I've tried both ways, but it is till not calling another css class when the div sticks to top:

You can see I've done for 2 options: { topSpacing: 0, className: "#newheader" } - #newheader should be showing a different color per CSS.

What am I missing? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sticky Plugin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, className: "#newheader" })
    });

  </script>


  <style>
    body {
      height: 10000px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #header {
      background: #bada55;
      color: white;
      font-family: Droid Sans;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.6em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      width:100%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    #newheader {
    background: #FF0004;
      color:#0056F2;
      font-family: Droid Sans;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.6em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      width:100%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is test this is text this is text at the top.</p>
  <div id="header">
    <p>This is the sticky thingy that is really cool.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is test this is text this is text at the bottom.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for edit @Zhuinden. I meant Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ClassName property adds a CLASS-name to the element. So its no ID!! Try:

```
$("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, className: "newheader" });
```

And alter your css like:

```
 .newheader {
      background: #FF0004;
      .....
  }
```

UPDATE:

After reading the Sticky documentation it was clear... The new class will be added to the parent element. So you must change you css cascading to:

```
.newheader #header {
   background: #FF0004;
   color:#0056F2;
   font-family: Droid Sans;
   font-size: 24px;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   width:100%;
   box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```

That will save your day!

Comment: I see. Updated, and now I see my change, but now it is not sticking..., however you can see the red box on scroll I've dumped it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=pwm3x547L0